# Fetch everything in a folder based on extension and put into zip

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ziparchive

I have to make 3 buttons. On button click I want to download all files from selected folder with correct extension in zip file. Eveything on wordpress site. The problem is, zip file is saving as .zip, but when I open it in notepad, there's HTML code. Thanks for help!

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['3dsdownload'])) {dddownloads();}
        
function dddownloads(){
    $dir = realpath("/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/");
    $scan_arr = scandir($dir);
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('3ds.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $files = array_diff($scan_arr, array('.','..') );
        
    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        if (!is_dir($file)){
            $filePath = $dir.$file;
            $file_ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ($file_ext=="3ds" || $file_ext=="3DS") {
                $zip->addFile($filePath, basename($filePath));
                }       
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
        
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=3ds.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile('3ds.zip');
    exit;
}
        ?>
        
        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="3dsdownload"
                value="3dsdownload"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: _"When I open it in notepad, there's HTML code"_ You can't open a .zip file with Notepad. You need to unzip it first.

Comment: @kmoser I can't unzipt it, because I get invalid zip.

Comment: You should check the return result of `$zip->open()`, `$zip->addFile()`, and `$zip->close()` to determine if they are working.

Comment: Archive zip is de facto working, saving files inside, but html (idk why) too. I think the problem is path. Root path for this script is /autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/themes/astra and I want files into zip from /autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/ Can I force path to be absolute? Independent from root path of script?

Comment: b>Warning</b>:  scandir(/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in <b>/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/themes/astra/DownloadALL.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br /> - That's my point. I can't define correct path. Any solutions? Or I just need to move script to correct folder?

Comment: I fixed path problem with this: $dir = (dirname(__DIR__,2)."/uploads/");

Comment: But still zip saves html code inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was buffer and path. After adding `ob_clean()` and fixing path, everything works fine! Final code:

```
<?php //Strona z pobieraniem wszystkich plikow z podziałem na formaty
//3ds
if(isset($_POST['3dsdownload'])) {dddownloads();}
    
function dddownloads(){
    ob_clean();
    $dir = (dirname(__DIR__,2)."/uploads/");
    $scan_arr = scandir($dir);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('3ds.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
    $files = array_diff($scan_arr, array('.','..') );
    
    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        if (!is_dir($file)){
            $filePath = $dir.$file;
            $file_ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ($file_ext=="3ds" || $file_ext=="3DS") {
                $zip->addFile($filePath, basename($filePath));
            }       
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=3ds.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_end_clean();
    readfile('3ds.zip');
    exit;
}
?>
```